# Google ,facebook sdk conflict

Tags: android, sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

Iam new to android,when a tried to include google  pluse sdk and facebook SDK in same project,
the IDE shows error in my code(The method that i have written for gpluse login become undefined).Someone plese tell me how can i manage 2 sdk at same time in android .